# The database alias name or database name "" could not be found. SQLSTATE=42705

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, db2

I am using .Net Core 2.1 to build an application and below is my `appsetting.json` file entry for the data connection. I am using an alias to connect to the database. This setting works for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 app but not for the .Net Core app.

I am using **IBM.Data.DB2.Core** NuGet package. If I replace **myaliasname** with the actual database name it connects successfully. I do not want to use the direct connection as the alias has alternate connections defined in case of failure.

```
"ConnectionStringOptions": {
    "datasource": "Database=myaliasname;UID={0};PWD={1};Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=1;Max Pool Size=100;"
  }
```

How can I use an alias in .Net Core app for Db2?

Comment: How exactly did you define the alias?

Comment: .Net  Core does not support sql alias since it is not cross-platform, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327293/issues-with-sql-alias-in-connectionstring-in-appsettings-json